# Swiss system chess tournament

Tags: time-control, swiss-pairing

In a swiss system chess tournament, how long should a round last? If a player exceeds his time who will be the winner?

Comment: Do you know about chess clocks ? If not, google that. Swiss tournaments can be played with various time controls. In any kind of tournament, if in a game a player exceeds his time, his opponent wins (or there's a draw in some special cases, e.g. if he has a bare king).

Answer (score 3):

Swiss system has nothing to do with time controls. It is a tournament pairing system based on the principle that in each round players with so far similar results are paired together, and that each player has approximately as many games with white and black. Details can be found in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-system_tournament).